# git clone error command not found error

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch, git

When I ssh into my raspberry pi 3 and try to use the command:git clone https://github.com/sunfounder/Sunfounder_Smart_Video_Car_Kit_for_RaspberryPi.git

it gives me the error message:-bash: $: command not found

Does any know how to fix this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a simple misspelling.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev it belongs to a software for `Raspberry Pi`

Comment: @scitronboy You could make it an answer

Comment: @Ingo Questions about problems that cannot be reproduced don't belong anywhere. I'm quite sure a `git clone` command cannot result in bash complaining about `$`.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I can reproduce it. _Luke_ has copied the suggested command `$ git clone <url>` together with `$`. So if you execute it (with `$` at the beginning) you get just the error message from bash as shown.

Answer (score 1):

according to your error message: `bash: $: command not found`, you must have put a dollar sign($) in front of your command. for example, it looks like you typed

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sunfounder/Sunfounder_Smart_Video_Car_Kit_for_RaspberryPi.git
```

to clone the repsotory. I don't know which tutorial you used to learn how to use the command line, but when you read an example of a command, you never put a `$` in front. the `$` just stands for the command prompt, you don't actually type it(for example, look at the end of your prompt: it probably looks something like `pi@hostname:~ $`, the `$` is already there.) so retry your command, and this time, just type

```
git clone https://github.com/sunfounder/Sunfounder_Smart_Video_Car_Kit_for_RaspberryPi.git
```

without the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

it would appear git is not installed.....

```
sudo apt-get install git
```